# ISNUMBER() - Shows for cell formatted as number FALSE

Tags: google-sheets

**Issue**:

- Cell C1 fetches a number from a web page via IMPORTXML.
- Cell B1 refers to it (=C1).
- B1 and C1 are formatted as number and also display numbers.

However, ISNUMBER for both cells is FALSE and thee shown decimals in B1 and C1 cannot be changed. Even if I copy the format of a cell D1, where ISNUMBER returns TRUE, to B1 and C1, it remains FALSE there.

What could be the reason if a cell is formatted as a number, a number is visible there (via formula) and yet ISNUMBER returns FALSE?

Comment: If you type the word "cat" into a cell and format it as a number, it's still going to say "cat." In the same way, if you have a string "10.123" in a cell and format it as a number, it doesn't *become* a number. It's still just a string that looks like a number. You can convert strings-that-look-like-numbers to real numbers is by preforming some non-transformable math on them. For example, instead of `=C1` try something like `=C1*1`. This will work whether the value in C1 is a string *or* a number, and is a good approach if you aren't sure or if there might be a mix of strings and real numbers.

Comment: @ErikTyler A good, succinct, well-expressed comment. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Tedinoz. I just did that.

Answer (score 1):

If you type the word "cat" into a cell and format it as a number, it's still going to say "cat." In the same way, if you have a string "10.123" in a cell and format it as a number, it doesn't become a number. It's still just a string that looks like a number. You can convert strings-that-look-like-numbers to real numbers is by performing some non-transformable math on them. For example, instead of `=C1` try something like `=C1*1`. This will work whether the value in C1 is a string or a number, and is a good approach if you aren't sure or if there might be a mix of strings and real numbers.